# ActiveMQ list queues in grails

Tags: grails, activemq-classic

I have a problem with activemq in grails. 
I want to get all the queues from activemq. My method worked fine until I updated the active mq server to version 5.13.0
Now my code does not work any more.

Here is my code:

```
 def connect = JMXConnectorFactory.connect(jmxUrl,env)
 def server = connect.MBeanServerConnection
 def allQueues=[]
 def query = new ObjectName('org.apache.activemq:BrokerName=localhost,type=Broker,destinationType=Queue,destinationName=*')
 def queues = server.queryNames(query, null )
 queues.each {
    allQueues.add(it.getKeyProperty("Destination"))
 }
```

I already changed the ObjectName like explained in: http://activemq.apache.org/activemq-580-release.html

But queues is always empty. 
What is the problem here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

found the solution, BrokerName is wrong, right is brokerName.

```
def query = new ObjectName('org.apache.activemq:brokerName=localhost,type=Broker,destinationType=Queue,destinationName=*')
```